# Need Help, Handlebars.RegisterHelper

Tags: express, handlebars.js

I am creating a simple JSExpress blog with handlebars, I want to be able to delete a comment only if the user who wrote the comment is logged in, so I need to create a helper to check if the Id of the logged user is the same as the author Id of the comment, I am trying and reading stuff a whole day now and still can't figure out where exactly should I write the Handlebars.RegisterHelper() function, and what else should I do or include before that and where( in which file ), if is there a step by step guide that wasn't able to find, or if anyone ca n explain it to me will be super cool and I will be very gratefull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `express-hbs`, but other handlebars express implementations should be the same.

It's quite straight forward once you've done it a few times. Here an example:

```
const hbs = require('express-hbs');

hbs.registerHelper("boolToCheckbox", function boolToCheckbox(bool) {
  if (bool) return "checked";
});
```

In the above example I'm converting Java object boolean fields, over to "checked" for use in a HTML checkbox variable. An example of it's usage is.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="isMaintainer" name="is_maintainer" {{boolToCheckbox is_maintainer}}>
```

So very simply, registerHelper should take in a string which is the name you'll use in handlebars to call the function, and then the function. The function itself will take whatever you pass it (in the above case it's a boolean property called `is_maintainer`) and will return whatever you tell it to. This could be more complex HTML code, or it could be something as simple as a string.

In your case, your function would probably take in the user and author objects, compare the ID field and return a true or false. You can then use it in an if statement to determine if you show an HTML element or not.

Comment: I know how the helper should look like, but what I can't figure out is in which file to ad the code so it will be visible from my hbs file, should it be in some controller or in app.js file or somewhere else, wherever I put it it throws an error helper Missing helper: "helperName"

Comment: If you're using express-hbs, then literally any file that is loaded in your app. So perhaps that's the index.js / app.js, or somewhere that you setup express. If you're using another library, then anywhere you have access to the handlebars object, so again most probably the index.js / app.js (where you setup express). Though you'd probably want to pull it out into a new file as you build up more and more helpers.

Comment: the whole time my mistake was at the require, when I use it like this const hbs = require('hbs'), works perfectly, thanks for the pointers